# Calculating speed at points via window functions

Tags: postgis

I want to calculate speed at every point for each device_id, such that there is a new column of "speed" attached to the current dataset

My dataset is like:

```
imei(device_id)         point_geom(SRID 4326)           time_created
```

Here is my code so far:

```
select st_distance((points_geom::geography),lag(points_geom::geography) over (partition by imei order by time_created))
 / nullif(( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_created) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LAG(time_created) OVER(PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY time_created)))::FLOAT8,0)  as speed
from dataset
```

Even though I am getting a result set, the values for speed are a bit lower than expected, and there are many zero's as well. Am I calculating the speed correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "lower as expected"? With that query, the speed is given in `m/s` - just in case this is not clear.

Comment: I just was concerned about the prevalence of so many 0's in the speed column, so I thought I might be calculating speed incorrectly.

Comment: Do you think the code looks okay?

Comment: If you don't want zeros then you can constrain updates to require location change. Since GPS is often highly variable, you might be better off collecting a one minute rolling average (which might compute faster as well) using a join on sensor ID and the first reading recorded a minute previously.